# AngularJS Controller not populating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint

This code runs on a SharePoint Web Part page in a Script Editor web part.  It makes an AJAX call to get list items from SharePoint, and then it should be populating the form with those items.  However, nothing is happening.

```
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<h2>Questionnaire:</h2>
<br />
<div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="spListCtrl">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="2" class="employee-table">
            <tr ng-repeat="control in Controls">
                <td>{{control.Title}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="{{control.Id}}" value="Yes">Yes
                    <input type="radio" name="{{control.Id}}" value="No">No
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="{{control.Id}}Comment"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
<script>
    function getDataWithCaml(listName, caml) {
        var endpoint = "https://myteamsite.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={\"ViewXml\":\"'" + caml + "'\"}";
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: endpoint,
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        });
    }

    var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute'])
    .controller('spListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        var caml = "<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>C-04</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>";
        var jsonData = getDataWithCaml("Controls", caml);
        jsonData.success(function (data) {
            alert('success');
            $scope.Controls = data.d.results;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Wrap the call `$scope.Controls = data.d.results;` in `$scope.$apply` and check

Comment: That did it.  Add a reply and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are updating scope outside the context of Angular execution, you need to wrap the assignment in $scope.$apply, such as

```
$scope.$apply(function() { 
  $scope.Controls = data.d.results;
});
```